How to prevent "Completed 304 NOT_MODIFIED" when hitting swagger URL on a Spring boot application?
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html - Getting "Completed 304 NOT_MODIFIED"
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?test - working
I have implemented OncePerRequestFilter on Spring boot application.
My objective is to validate the user before sending the request to Controller.
If the URL has swagger then I am not validating the user
I've implemented the following code. Everthing is working as expected except swagger URL. When I hit Swagger URL I am getting
a empty screen with the error message "Completed 304 NOT_MODIFIED". When I add any dummy query parameter in the URL, Swagger UI
is working. How to prevent this from happening? This was working perfectly when I used use Filter->doFilter. This stopped working
after implementing OncePerRequestFilter->doFilterInternal
Any help is appreciated.
@Component
public class SecurityFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  
  @Override
  protected boolean shouldNotFilterAsyncDispatch() {
      return false;
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    val requestToCache = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
    val responseToCache = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);

    String path = requestToCache.getRequestURI();
    boolean noAuthRequiredPath = Pattern.matches(ALLOWED_PATHS, path);
    
    if (noAuthRequiredPath) {
      //filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
      filterChain.doFilter(requestToCache, responseToCache);
      responseToCache.copyBodyToResponse();
    } else
    {
      //check wheathe the use is a valid user
      //if valid use
      //filterChain.doFilter(requestToCache, responseToCache);
      //else
      //write httpServletResponse
      //httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json");
      //httpServletResponse.setStatus(statusCode);
      //httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(responseJson);
      //httpServletResponse.getWriter().flush();
      responseToCache.copyBodyToResponse();
    }
}

